# Can't align images with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got an element on a page I'm doing that needs to display 3 centered and aligned images. (horizontaly)

However, I can't center them correctly on the screen. They appear more to the left than to the right or they appear aligned to the left on the span container.

Can anyone help me?

Here's the HTML

```
 <div class="row">


                    <div class="span12 logo-container">
                        <div class="span9 logo-wrapper">
                        <div class="logo">                                
                            <img src="img/siemens_log.png" />                              
                        </div>



                             <div class="logo">
                                 <img src="img/merck_logo.png" />
                             </div>



                         <div class="logo archdaily"> 
                             <img src="img/archdaily_logo.png" />
                         </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>


         </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.logo-wrapper
{
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;


}
.logo-container 
{

    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;


}


.logo
{
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    text-align: center;

}



.archdaily
{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They appear more to the left than to the right because of this declaration:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You're giving them a right margin of 20px, which effectively pushes them to the left.  Get rid of that margin and they will appear more centered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want them all centered and on top of each other (vertical). I would just use `text-align: center;`. That will work for text and images (not divs).

Example...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">

      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="img/siemens_log.png" />
      </div>

      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="img/merck_logo.png" />
      </div>

      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="img/archdaily_logo.png" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Something to note...You may already know this. I saw you were using `margin: 0 auto;`. That will center a div IF you give that div a width. If you don't give it a width then it will default to 100% width. And as you can see if you center a div that spans 100% horizontally, you won't see any visual difference.

If I didn't understand your question, then let me know and I'll try to help.

**UPDATE**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

      <div class="span4" style="text-align: left;">
        <img src="img/siemens_log.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="span4" style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="img/merck_logo.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="span4" style="text-align: right;">
        <img src="img/archdaily_logo.png" />
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

They will appear horizontal now. I aligned the far right image to the right edge of the div so that the span of the row will take up the 940px (span12) width. I don't know how badly the image sizes differ between the images, but that will change how the gaps look between the images. If they are the same size, then everything should look even. Whatdyathink?

Comment: Nope. Sorry for not being specific, but I want them aligned horizontaly, side by side ;) I can align them verticaly, which I don't want

Comment: thank you for your reply. It doesn't look well. Neither the images appear centered. Also, the span4 class is way to big for my needs. It needs to be span2 for the images to have just the gutter spacing between them. The div needs to be 100% width so when the device size changes, the layout floats to the respective dimentions...